# Group, normality, and isomorphism question.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$ be a subgroup of $B$ and $B$ be a subgroup of $G$. $A$ and $B$ are normal in $G$.

1. Show that the image $B/A$ of $B$ in $G/A$ is normal.
2. Show that $G/B$ is isomorphic to $(G/A)/(B/A)$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not "the" subgroup but "a" subgroup. What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: Key search phrase: "third isomorphism theorem".

Comment: @YACP I am trying to edit it, so that the full version is blocked, and appears only when the mouse is on that area. But I am not sure how to do this. Might you teach me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @awllower, use >! instead of >

Comment: @AndreasCaranti As can be seen, it becomes kind of strange, that is, there is a mark without function now... I am not sure where it goes wrong, though. Per chance you can edit my answer to fix that? Thanks if it is not too troublesome.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
As I later found out that this is tagged homework, I think I should write a more "hintive" one, so that one could work it out by oneself.
If one wants to show that some subgroup is normal, then one should find a homomorphism that takes the given subgroup to $0$ in another group; and then the quotient group would be isomorphic with the image in that other group. So, what group is the quotient required to be isomorphic? And what homomorphism fulfills this condition?

> **Full Answer.**  Since normal subgroups are nothing but the kernels of homomorphisms, we can suppose that $A$ is the kernel of $f: G\to G/A$, and $B$ the kernel of $g: G\to G/B$. Then $B/A$ is just $f(B)$. Let us draw the situation in the form of exact sequences: $0\to A\to G\to G/A\to 0$, $0\to B\to G\to G/B\to 0$, $0\to B/A\to G/A\to G/B\to 0$. The last sequence makes sense since $A\subseteq B$. The results thus follow quite immediately.

Maybe this is not so appropriate to appear here?
In any case, hope this helps, and thanks for the attention.